# Laravel - last login date and time timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I know there are fields automatically inserted (e.g. *updated_at* and *created_at*) but I was wondering if there is like an Eloquent method *timestamp()* or the Laravel way to produce timestamps?

For instance, I want to record a timestamp every time a user logs in to my system and store it into the database, so we can see each user's last login date and time details.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may observe the `auth.login` event and update the user's last login time.  See the first example in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events) for events to accomplish exactly what you're trying to do.

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user) {
    $user->last_login = new DateTime;

    $user->save();
});
```

**Note**: In 4.0, the event name is `user.login`.  In 4.1, the event name is `auth.login`

### Update

It's really up to you where you put your Event listeners.  If you read the linked to doc page, it states:

> So, you know how to register events, but you may be wondering where to
>   register them. Don't worry, this is a common question. Unfortunately,
>   it's a hard question to answer because you can register an event
>   almost anywhere! But, here are some tips. Again, like most other
>   bootstrapping code, you may register events in one of your start files
>   such as app/start/global.php.
>
> If your start files are getting too crowded, you could create a
>   separate app/events.php file that is included from a start file. This
>   is a simple solution that keeps your event registration cleanly
>   separated from the rest of your bootstrapping. If you prefer a class
>   based approach, you may register your events in a service provider.
>   Since none of these approaches is inherently "correct", choose an
>   approach you feel comfortable with based on the size of your
>   application.

My personal preference would be to register them within a Service Provider, since that would keep them segregated and to me is the more 'Laravel' way of doing things.  If you need help with service providers, see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#service-providers) documentation entry.

However, if you really just want to get something up and running as quickly as possible, it would be just as easy for you to register that listener inside of `app/start/global.php`

Comment: Wow thanks for the reply. It seems like exactly what I wanted. However how do I use this? I am new to Laravel

Comment: thanks again! I just tried putting the block of code into the global.php and it works! Will definitely check out the Service Provider.

Comment: Latest reference for the Laravel Auth Events: https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#events

Answer (score 86):

In Laravel 5.2+ (tested on 5.6 as well) the process is a little different. First, add your listener to the EventServiceProvider:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSuccessfulLogin',
    ],
];
```

Then do:

```
php artisan event:generate
```

Which will create a new listener in app/Listeners. Now edit your Listener to touch the date in the last_login column in your users table:

```
public function handle(Login $event)
{
    $event->user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $event->user->save();
}
```

Make sure the Listener created by Artisan has the correct namespaces at the top. For this particular case the correct namespaces in your Listener should be:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
```

Comment: Awesome, I would have never figured this out on my own.
If you would rather use the time in the DB, you could do:<br>
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`
<br>... <br>
`$event->user->last_login = DB::raw('now()');`

Comment: How does the $event object get the user object into it? Is this event fired deep in Laravel somewhere?

Comment: The Login event already exists. It lives here: Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login and it's passed to your method whenever you add a listener to Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login. It all happens automatically.

Comment: FYI `InteractsWithQueue` is only needed if you need interaction (`delete`, `release`, etc) with the queue, in this case it's not necessary.

Answer (score 42):

Just add this code below into your App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php

At the top of your controller:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

And inside your controller put this function below:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
    $user->last_login = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Simple.

Comment: This should be the best answer... and the easiest as well...

Comment: yeah! but should add this column to your users table 'last_login' as timestamp. Then in your view add. {{ Auth::user()->last_login }} But it has sense? if you loggin again it will update.. you will never know if one user accesed to your system only if you check your database will know, buf you like user of the system you can't know because it will update. It has sense checking only your database before make login. Ok guys but you can show the last_loggin before to update, get the last_login value and save it in a session and then update the column..

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar question. In case you don't feel the need the use events you can update the timestamp after you authenticate the user. I put the following code in my controller method that handles the user authentication.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password))) {
    Auth::user()->last_login = new DateTime();
    Auth::user()->save();
    return Redirect::intended('/');
} else {
    return Redirect::to('account/login');
}
```

This does the job for me.

Comment: I think that in this solution you miss logins by autologin mechanism.