# Laravel Event Listening

Tags: laravel, eloquent, event-listener

I have an issue similar to this post :
[Laravel - last login date and time timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460066/laravel-last-login-date-and-time-timestamp)

**In short, my purpose and question is :**

1. I have a "**logrecords**" table in my database.
2. My event listeners in **global.php** are just working on default "**users**" table.
3. I want my **event listeners** are able to insert data on my "**logrecords**" table.

How can i do that :

1. Should i configure my database tables using which are using **eloquent** ?
2. Or should i change something in **global.php** ?

Thanks for your support.

--------------------Update--------------------

I realized that in my **auth.php** file, default authentication model has been set as :

```
'model' => 'User'
```

But i want to listen and work with both **User** and **Logrecord** model.So that when i try to listen events in my **global.php** file, laravel is automatically trying to work with User model. So that i had to configure my event listeners like that :

Part of my **global.php** file :

```
//First Example
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{   
    $userLogRecord = Logrecord::firstOrCreate(array('user_id' => $user->id));
    $userLogRecord->user_id = $user->id;
    $userLogRecord->login_last_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $userLogRecord->save();
});

//Second Example
Event::listen('auth.logout', function($user)
{    
    $userLogRecord = Logrecord::firstOrCreate(array('user_id' => $user->id));
    $userLogRecord->user_id = $user->id;
    $userLogRecord->logout_last_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $userLogRecord->save();
});
```

It is working for now, but I am thinking that it's not a good idea to edit my listeners like that. **My purpose is to listen and do some process with both User and Logrecord models.** It serves my purpose right now but i feel like i have to improve.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

@DemonDrake,

If I understand correctly you simply want to add data to a "log" table?
In the most simple form, the answer is "Yes you would use the eloquent ORM for that

```
class Log extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'log';

}
```

or perhaps query builder even.
There are a number of ways this is possible. I personally suggest you check out https://laracasts.com/lessons

Comment: I can add data into my log table, but i want to do this with event listeners. But my current event listeners are trying to insert data into default users table. I want my listeners to work with my log class (model)

Comment: I assume You already have the listeners in place so just fire the events. It would help to see your existing code, however I would do it like this:
http://laravel.io/bin/aNB1N

Comment: Eddy, thank you for giving me some ideas, i edited the post, thought I had to improve my code.