# How to get the login log in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2, I would want to record user's login log, including login time and ip address, what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460066/laravel-last-login-date-and-time-timestamp/34521860#34521860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$ip = Request::ip();
$loginTime = Carbon::now();
Log::info('User logged in with '.$ip.' at '.$loginTime);
```

Please read [Logging documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#logging).