# How to update the last login column when the user successful login with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update the last login column when the user successful login, I tried putting the code below in LoginController, but it didn't work, I've tried with  a listener too, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34521860/6569823), but it didn't work, nothing ever happened, seems like the listener wasn't being executed.

```
        DB::table('users')
              ->where('id', Auth::id())
              ->update(['lastlogin' => Carbon::now()]);
```

My laravel version is   5.4.12. How can I get it working?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `Login` event fired after a user has been successfully authenticated.

In `app/providers/EventServiceProvider.php`, add the event and listener to the `$listen` array.

```
protected $listen = [
    // ...
    \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class => [
        \App\Listeners\LastLogin::class,
    ],
    // ...
];
```

Create a new event listener in `app/listeners/LastLogin.php`

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Models\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;

class LastLogin
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        // Update user last login date/time
        $event->user->update(['lastlogin' => Carbon::now()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I've solved it.  I also add a login_count to check user activity in this manner: 


    $event->user->login_count = $event->user->login_count + 1;

Comment: Yeah, if you want to increment a login counter, I'd use the following to keep things nice and tight. `$event->user->increment('login_count')->update(['lastlogin' => Carbon::now()]);`

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, the only thing I had to to different was that I used this query to update: `DB::table('users')
              ->where('id', $event->user->id)
              ->update(['lastlogin' => Carbon::now()]);` , for some odd reason the way you used didn't work for me.

Comment: No error, but it didn't update the last_login column.

Comment: Just checking, but you're aware that the attribute being updated by the query is lastlogin not last_login, as per your original question?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, I changed it after posting the question, that's not the problem.

Comment: Is the attribute fillable or not guarded on your model?