# Notify user when next time user login in Laravel 5.4 Application

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am looking for a solution to notify all the users for occurrence of X activity in the app.

I am not looking for notification by mail or sms. Because this specific notification would be send to all the users, which could be anywhere between 1000 to 25000 users. sending 1000s of mail or sms is waste of resources.

I want to notify users using something which goes noticed, that is they would read. for example: if the X activity has happened today. And Y user logins after 10 days he/she must be able to see the notification (I guess flash message wont work in this case).

What is the best and most efficient way possible? if notification using database is the way that I think. How can I create a single notification (single entry in database) and make sure all the users read that notification next time login? without creating 1000s of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think storing notifications in the database would be the way to go too.

If you add a many-to-many relationship between your `User` and `Notification` models, with a `is_read` flag on the relationship pivot table.

Then when a user reads the notification, you update the `is_read` flag to `1`. Alternatively, if you don't need to keep the notification for that user, you could delete the relationship, thus reducing storage of obsolete records.

**Edit**

If every user will always see every notification, then you could store the `last_login_at` timestamp on your `User` model, which is updated each time a user logs in.

Then each time a user logs in, find all `Notification`s created since the `last_login_at` and show them to the user.

Comment: I thought of the same. so when I create new notification. I should add 1000s or rows in many to many relation pivot table? one row for each user with is_read to 0. I think there is a better solution out there. Like: When user logins all the notification not seen by X user should be shown on dashboard page and automatically delete behind the scene. Or I was thinking of creating a single row entry of notification in database and show it in the dashboard for one week or 2 weeks and remove the row after that.

Comment: Will every user **always** see every notification?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by every notification. Do you mean other notifications in the system too? I am handling other types of notification using flash msg which is for user who are online and does some activity to their account.

Comment: I mean if a notification is created, should every user see it? I.e. there are not different notifications for different user levels, or departments, etc?

Comment: yes, everyone must see (There is only one kind of user.). Before the idea was to send email to everyone using queue but then it was waste of resource.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added an alternative approach.

Comment: Laravel updated_at field is the one I am looking for then I guess? or do I create a new field to achieve this.

Comment: I'd create a new field, because if a user edits their record, it'd change the `updated_at` field. Checkout my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475051/how-to-update-the-last-login-column-when-the-user-successful-login-with-laravel/42475926#42475926

Comment: The lastlogin bit stores date-time but then lastlogin updates as soon as I login. So, I dont get the user lastlogin detail instead I get current login date-time, which seems to be wrong. what should I do?

Comment: So in the event listener, you could store the previous last login date/time in the user's session before updating it. Or you could use `$user->getOriginal('last_login_at')` to get the original value.

Comment: where do I put $user->getOriginal('last_login_at') ? do I have to create one or there already exists 'last_login_at' ?

Comment: Look through the source code for `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php` and you'll see the method defined there. It will only give you the previous value whilst using the same instance, and if you only save the model once.