# How to detect first login in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm just starting out on Laravel and  building an application with Laravel 5.4. I wish to implement a functionality that detects when a user first log in into my application. This is because a form view will be served to the user when he/she logs in for the first time to enable them complete their profile.I've Googled around and couldn't find such functionality shipped with Laravel. I've thought about adding a first_login column to the user's table and set it to true and the moment a user logs in the column goes to false irreversibly.I need guidance on how to implement such functionality.

Comment: You're on the right track. Add a `first_login` Boolean column, or better yet, add a `last_login` timestamp column. If `last_login` is NULL, then it's their first login.

Comment: Thanks @kirk.Is it OK to query the database for the value of the column right in my view blade file,so as to redirect accordingly?

Comment: Generally speaking, you'd do that check in your Controller rather than the View, but that's entirely up to you.

Comment: You may find my answer to another question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475051/how-to-update-the-last-login-column-when-the-user-successful-login-with-laravel/42475926#42475926

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check like that if user login first time in your laravel application

```
// Hint: Auth::user() is the currently signed in user object.
$first_time_login = false;
if (Auth::user()->first_time_login) {
    $first_time_login = true;
    Auth::user()->first_time_login = 1; // Flip the flag to true
    Auth::user()->save(); // By that you tell it to save the new flag value into the users table
}
```

Comment: are `$first_time_login` and `auth::user()->first_time_login` two different things?