# Laravel detect first login and save it to Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to show a user a welcoming message the first time he logs in. I have followed this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475051/how-to-update-the-last-login-column-when-the-user-successful-login-with-laravel/42475926#42475926) and have created a listener file looking like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class LastLogin
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        if ($event->user->last_login === null) {
            $event->user->isFirstLogin = true;
            $event->user->save();
        }
        // Update user last login date/time
        $event->user->update(['last_login' => now()]);
    }
}
```

To test this, in my Controller I did this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $isFirstLogin = Auth::user()->isFirstLogin;
        Log::info($isFirstLogin);
        return view('myView');
    }
```

However the output in my Log File is empty. How can I fix this?

This code in my listener is also not working:

```
public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->last_login === null) {
            Auth::user()->isFirstLogin = true;
            Auth::user()->save();
        }
        // Update user last login date/time
        Auth::user()->update(['last_login' => now()]);
    }
```

In my User model I added:

```
//status
public $isFirstLogin = false;
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: The last_login column in my database is working perfectly

Comment: adding a property to the class wont do anything, it needs to be an attribute in the database or an accessor/mutator ... you only need the `last_login` field though, if there is no datetime set they have never logged in before, if there is a datetime set, they have logged in at least once before

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right that I can check if a datetime is set and that is exactly what I am trying to do. My problem is, that I have to check this in the handle function of my Login-Listener because if I check afterwards the datetime will never be null because I set it already (Auth::user()->update(['last_login' => now()]);)  Do you know how to save a boolean property to the currently authenticated user so I can later do something like this: Auth::user()->isFirstLogin //should return whether or not it is the first login of this user

Comment: sure you could actually set something on it for this single 'instance', but if you go to put that user from the database again it wont have that data obviously ... you could create an accessor and mutator that actually sets a property instead of an attribute for you, or just regular methods that you can call