# Larevel - Save last user request timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration

I want to save the datetime of last interaction of a user with the application inside the user table.

I'm using Laravel 8.

I added a column in users table (last_interaction):

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->integer('id', true);
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('username', 192);
            $table->string('email', 192);
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone', 192);
            $table->integer('role_id');
            $table->boolean('statut')->default(1);
            $table->datetime('last_interaction'); //The column where to save the datetime of last interaction
            $table->timestamps(6);
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Is it possible to update the users table with each request done! or should i do it on login only (for Optimisations) ?

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460066/laravel-last-login-date-and-time-timestamp .
But that's not the case, i want to update the date when there is any interaction with the application, not only on login.

Comment: You could try registering some [global middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#global-middleware) which will check if the user is currently authenticated and update a field from inside. This means it would trigger on each new HTTP request.

Comment: @MatthewBradley Can you explain more! like where do you update the field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make new middleware with this command `php artisan make:middleware LastInteraction`

**App\Http\Middleware\LastInteraction.php:**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->last_interacted = Carbon::now();
        $user->save();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This will set a field of last_interacted to the current time given this field exists in your migration. If it doesn't exist [create one](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#creating-columns).

**App\Http\Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [

    (...)

    \App\Http\Middleware\LastInteraction::class,
];
```

This will register the middleware to be applied globally to each route.

Comment: Do i have to apply  `LastInteraction` Middleware on all routes?

Comment: Adding it to the kernel registers the middleware to fire on each route. If you want to add them manually, skip this step and include it on the routes you want it on. If you want to exclude only specific routes, you can use the `->withoutMiddleware(...)` function on the route